# Что использовать Spring или Struts?

Tags: java, spring, mvc, struts

Хожу на тренинги. Недавно начались фреймворки, и рассматривался с большего Struts 1.2. Ещё впереди Struts 2 + Spring. Мне нужно сдать небольшой проект. Немного успел познакомиться со Spring (сам до этого) и начал писать проект (написал пока что вход в систему и страницу пользователя).

Встает вопрос, что использовать Spring или Struts?

Struts, как я понял - это чистый MVC Framework, а Spring MVC  это всего лишь один из модулей Spring.  Ещё слышал, что используют их сочетания.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы правильно поняли: есть Spring MVC, который делает нечто подобное тому, что делает Struts. У Struts на борту есть неплохой набор JSP-тэгов и EL-функций. В Spring также имеется свой в виде отдельного модуля. В этом смысле Spring MVC + co и Struts предоставляют аналогичный функционал.

Но, на мой взгляд Spring MVC развивается быстрее, чем Struts. Кроме того, Spring сам по себе может быть очень полезен в большом проекте. И да, Spring 3 предоставляет много хороших плюх. По мне я бы никогда не стал использовать Spring MVC более ранних версий, потому что не было смысла. Но в новом спринге очень удобно настраивать веб-компоненты с помощью аннотаций и делает за вам много рутинной работы. В использовании же их одновременно по сути не вижу большого смысла по выше указанным причинам.

Comment: Ничего подобного, что развивается быстрее или медленнее вы не можете знать.

Comment: @RomanC это почему же? Как вы это определили? Можно всегда понять по динамике трендов и по количеству коммитов. По-вашему, это что-то из категории непознаваемого?

Comment: @cyber Вы можете познавать динамику трендов и количество комитов, только это надо правильно считать. Поскольку вы не написали здесь результаты исследований и не привели статистику, то вы не можете знать это.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу, что Struts 1.2 уже давно не развивается и удален с сайта апачи. Его приемником стал WebWork или Struts2 в новом названии. Я так понимаю, что если поменялось название, то и следовательно поменялась архитектура, которая сильно отличается у обоих фреймворков.

[Spring MVC](https://spring.io/) - это web-фреймворк являющийся одним из модулей Spring. Используется реализация MVC1 как в Struts 1. Наибольшая польза от этого фреймворка что он легко интегрируется в другие модули Spring, необходимые для развития вашего проекта.

[Struts2](https://struts.apache.org/) - это web-фреймворк построенный на базе сервлетов, реализующий MVC2. Он может расширяться с помощью плагинов и интегрироваться в другие фреймворки, в том числе и Spring.

В чем отличие, если не в архитектуре, то первый на мой взгляд более простой и требует меньше времени на изучение. Второй  - намного больше и сложнее, требует гораздо больше времени на изучение. Понятно, что время потраченное на изучение потом окупается. То, что касается скорости развития, то первый на мой взгляд развивается гораздо быстрее.

Оба фреймворка можно использовать как на фронтэнде так и на бакэнде. Если у вас есть вопрос что использовать, или что лучше использовать, то я вам сразу скажу, что это ваш выбор, и не только ваш. Многие используют первый фреймворк, потому, что он является частью Spring. Если вы хотите сделать ваш простой проект быстро, то первый вам больше подходит, но если у вас больше времени и возможностей, чтобы тратить их на изучение второго фреймворка, то это может вам подойти. Я вообще-то не представляю практическое использование второго без интеграции в Spring, но опять же это моё личное мнение.