# Повторная отправка формы из-за отсутствия кэша

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

**Мой начальный код:**

```
public class LogoutCommand implements Command{

    private static final String PAGE = "/index.jsp";

    @Override
    public CommandResult execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServiceException {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        return CommandResult.forward(PAGE);
    }}
```

**jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:setLocale value="${sessionScope.local}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="message"/>
<fmt:message key="title.course" var="heading"/>
<fmt:message key="button.edit" var="edit"/>
<fmt:message key="button.submit" var="submitText"/>
<fmt:message key="placeholder.enterNewRequirement" var="enterRequirement"/>
<html>
<head>
    <title>${heading}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/course-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/language-all-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/general-style.css">
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="fragments/header.jsp"/>
<main>
    <nav class="nameCourse">
        <h3><c:out value="${nameCourse}"/></h3>
    </nav>
    <nav>
        <c:if test="${submit == null}">
            <h3 class="requirement-title"><fmt:message key="h3.requirements"/></h3>
        </c:if>
        <nav class="requirements">
            <c:forEach var="requirement" items="${requirements}">
                <h5>
                    <li><c:out value="${requirement}" escapeXml="true"/></li>
                </h5>
            </c:forEach>
        </nav>

        <c:if test="${sessionScope.role == 'ADMIN'}">
            <table class="table-all">
                <tr>
                    <th><fmt:message key="th.username"/></th>
                </tr>

                <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${student.username}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>

            <nav class="edit-nav">
                <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller" method="post" class="edit-form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="nameCourse" value="${nameCourse}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="newRequirement"/>
                    <label for="newRequirement"><fmt:message key="lable.requirement"/> </label>
                    <textarea id="newRequirement" name="newRequirement" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit">${edit}</button>
                </form>
            </nav>

            <nav>
                <c:if test="${successRequirement != null}">
                    ${successRequirement}
                </c:if>
            </nav>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sessionScope.role == 'STUDENT'}">
            <c:if test="${submit == null}">
                <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="submitStudent">
                    <input type="hidden" name="nameCourse" value="${requestScope.nameCourse}">
                    <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 15px">${submitText}</button>
                </form>
            </c:if>

            <nav>
                <c:if test="${submit != null}">
                    ${submit}
                </c:if>
            </nav>
        </c:if>
    </nav>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet:**

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

private final CommandFactory commandFactory = new CommandFactory();

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    process(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    process(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    ConnectionPool connectionPool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    connectionPool.closeAllConnection();
}

private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String commandType = request.getParameter("command");
    Command action = commandFactory.create(commandType);
    String page;
    boolean isRedirect = false;
    try {
        CommandResult result = action.execute(request, response);
        page = result.getPage();
        isRedirect = result.isRedirect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
        page = "WEB-INF/view/errorPage.jsp";
    }
    if (!isRedirect) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(page);
    }
}
```

}

У меня была проблема, после **logout** я мог с помощью кнопки назад вернуться на прошлые страницы.

**Я сделал отдельный фильтр:**

```
    @WebFilter("/controller")
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Теперь я не могу после **logout** перейти на прошлые страницы с помощью кнопки назад в браузере, но теперь, если я хочу воспользоваться кнопкой назад на некоторых страницах мне **выскакивает вот это:**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я правильно понял, что это выскакивает из-за того, что у меня нет кэша? И как это исправить?

Comment: Нет, это потому, что в вашем фреймворке отсутствует фактори результата.

Comment: можно объяснить

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Если вы не понимаете почему со страницы повторно отправляются данные, то тем более не понять паттерн команды. Чтобы не изобретать велосипед, советую почитать  [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818691/204920).

Comment: Дело в том, что я могу использовать только JavaEE и всё, паттерн command я знаю. Я просто не понял про какой фактори результат идёт речь.