# Как передать параметр из одного метода контроллера в другой

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mvc, jsp

Не совсем понимаю, как правильно можно передать ключ моего entity из одного метода контроллера в другой. Т.е. ситуация такова: имеются 2 таблицы со связью one-to-many, я нажимаю на кнопку info и перехожу на страницу связанных сущностей, далее я нажимаю кнопку add и добавляю связанную сущность и, как я понял, должен сделать следующее - обращаюсь к методу в сервисе, которые вызывает метод в DAO и передаю ему конкретную родительскую сущность, на которой получаю через геттер лист связанных сущность, добавляю ее в лист и через сеттер устанавливаю для связанной сущности родительскую сущность, чтобы создать bi-directional связь. Вопросы такие: 1)Как мне верно передать родительскую сущность до нужного метода в контроллере, есть идея делать это через jsp файл постоянно поддерживая взаимоотношение view-контроллер, но тогда как это сделать, или же есть какой-то другой способ? 2) Верно ли реализован метод в DAO для добавления связанной сущности в БД?

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private WarehouseService warehouseService;
    @RequestMapping("/main")
    public String getAllTenants(Model model){
    List<Tenant> tenantList=warehouseService.getAllTenants();
    model.addAttribute("allTenants",tenantList);
        return "main-page";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/addNewTenant")
    public String addTenant(Model model){
        Tenant tenant=new Tenant();
        model.addAttribute("tenant",tenant);
        return "tenant-info";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/saveTenant")
    public String saveTenant(@ModelAttribute("tenant") Tenant tenant){
        warehouseService.addTenant(tenant);
    return "redirect:/main";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/allProductsInfo")
    public String getAllProducts(@RequestParam("placeNumber") int placeNumber,Model model){
        Tenant tenant=warehouseService.getTenant(placeNumber);
        List<Product> productList=warehouseService.getAllProducts(tenant);
        model.addAttribute("productList",productList);
        model.addAttribute("placeNumber",placeNumber);
        return "products-info";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/addNewProduct")
    public String addProduct(@RequestParam("placeNumber") int placeNumber, Model model){
        Product product=new Product();
        model.addAttribute("product",product);
        model.addAttribute("placeNumber",placeNumber);
        return "product-add";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/saveProduct")
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,@RequestParam("placeNumber") int placeNumber){
        Tenant tenant=warehouseService.getTenant(placeNumber);
        warehouseService.addProduct(product,tenant);
        return "redirect:/products-info";
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class WarehouseServiceImpl implements WarehouseService{

    @Autowired
    private TenantDAO tenantDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Tenant> getAllTenants() {
        List<Tenant> tenantList=tenantDAO.getAllTenants();
        return tenantList;
    }

    @Override
    public void addTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        tenantDAO.saveTenant(tenant);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(Tenant tenant) {
        tenant.setProduct(productDAO.getAllProducts(tenant.getPlaceNumber()));
        return tenant.getProduct();
    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product,Tenant tenant) {
        productDAO.saveProduct(product,tenant);

    }

    @Override
    public Tenant getTenant(int placeNumber) {
        Tenant tenant=tenantDAO.getTenant(placeNumber);
        return tenant;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(int placeNumber) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Product> productList=session.createSQLQuery("select * from my_db.products where place_number="+placeNumber).addEntity(Product.class).list();
        return productList;
    }


    @Override
    public void saveProduct(Product product,Tenant tenant) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        product.setTenant(tenant);
        if(tenant.getProduct()==null){
            tenant.setProduct(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        tenant.getProduct().add(product);
        session.saveOrUpdate(product);
    }

    /*@Override
    public void deleteProduct(int id) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    }*/
}
```

JSP файлы, которые есть

```
<html>
<head><%@ page isELIgnored="false" %></head>
<body>
<h2>All tenants</h2>
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Phone number</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th>Place number</th>
        <th>Operation</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="tenant" items="${allTenants}">

        <c:url var="infoButton" value="/allProductsInfo">
            <c:param name="placeNumber" value="${tenant.placeNumber}"></c:param>
        </c:url>

     <tr>
         <td>${tenant.name}</td>
         <td>${tenant.surname}</td>
         <td>${tenant.number}</td>
         <td>${tenant.summaryVolume}</td>
         <td>${tenant.placeNumber}</td>
         <td>
             <input type="button" value="Info"
                    onclick="window.location.href='${infoButton}'">

         </td>
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Add"
           onclick="window.location.href='addNewTenant'">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<head><%@ page isELIgnored="false" %></head>
<body>
<h2>All products</h2>
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <form:form action="saveProduct" modelAttribute="placeNumber">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${productList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.name}</td>
            <td>${product.volume}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form:form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<body>
<form:form action="saveProduct" modelAttribute="product" >
    Name <form:input path="name"></form:input>
    <br>
    <br>
    Volume <form:input path="volume"></form:input>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: view не поддерживает связи с контроллером, для того чтобы вызывать методы контроллера из view нужно ставить Struts, т.к. в в Spring контроллеры синглтоны то никак не получится, т.е. надо ставить другой запрос а промежуточные данные можно сохранять в сессии. См. отличие двух фреймворков [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818691/204920).

Comment: Здесь явно некорректна архитектура